# Return generic value from extended class in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have up to 3 classes:

```
abstract class Params {
    protected params = {};

    protected constructor() {}
}
```

```
abstract class ListParams extends Params {
    protected constructor() {
        super();
    }

    setSkip(skip: number): ListParams {
        this.params['skip'] = skip;

        return this;
    }
}
```

```
class MyEntityParams extends ListParams {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    setTitle(title: string): MyEntityParams {
        this.params['title'] = title;

        return this;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to chain the methods like this:

```
const myEntityParams = new MyEntityParams();

myEntityParams
  .setSkip(0)
  .setTitle('HelloWorld');
```

Since `setParams()` returns `ListParams`, i'm not able to call `setTitle()` on it. Can i use generics as return values to make this example work? If yes, how? `setSkip()` should return the `MyEntityParams` class. Using `any` as return value isn't really an option, because of the missing autocompletion in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types)  as a return type:

```
abstract class Params {
    protected params: Record<string, any> = {};

    protected constructor() {}
}
abstract class ListParams extends Params {
    protected constructor() {
        super();
    }

    setSkip(skip: number): this {
        this.params['skip'] = skip;

        return this;
    }
}
class MyEntityParams extends ListParams {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    setTitle(title: string): this {
        this.params['title'] = title;

        return this;
    }
}

const myEntityParams = new MyEntityParams();

myEntityParams
  .setSkip(0)
  .setTitle('HelloWorld');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=33&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsGBbDA3gLABQC5CADlAPYQCm89AJlTsPgFwIBKjNUZgB5IUAJYA7AOYAaBMAkBPAHwIAvAgIBfANylSFKrQZNWsGhNEBXeAIAUASk1bSLkqFFxEKNBgAyYpDYeBj0AB4MEswYwRyEBhTUdIwMZhbWtlCOmgmG5GBWlPRZDnpkFG65CGD0EADKANZilHZgTZTcEla4IMUO3BAAFoE55XkIQ4EAdJTs+ADaAORtzYsAuurV7WVVhlC1VlASE8NgZYZubj7oCACyigCiEhBiEIqx+AjhkdEIAUFzeJjJDpaA2CD2JzEYGGApFErnCr6YE1CAAFVeyHodheECx3FEkik-ROI2h43IkzAM0BS1xWPWm3p9B2MIo+wgh2OVMR5EuyPMlkQuEez1e70Bmwk9AA7ndRbiJSFHKyRU9FR8wAkpqjGs07AAGBza1EYvHYxYACXoyGQNAA6gJkMxFqUgA)